# How to make a string to associative array in php?

Tags: php

My string is `$string = 'ft=3&br=5&ly=2';` How to get an array from this string like this:

```
$array = array(
    'ft' => '3',
    'br' => '5',
    'ly' => '2'
);
```

Comment: there's a function for that https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php has a build in function for this:

[parse_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
$string = 'ft=3&br=5&ly=2';

parse_str($string,$out);

print_r($out);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [ft] => 3
    [br] => 5
    [ly] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP built-in function `parse_str()`, it will parse the string into variables.

```
<?php
        $string = 'ft=3&br=5&ly=2';
        parse_str($string, $output);
        print_r($output);
?>
```